# Common cache for wcf services launched in different servicehosts

Tags: wcf, iis, caching

I'm hosting my WCF application with IIS. To serve some methods I need a reference to helper object which is heavily initialized. A good scenario is to initialise it once and put in a cache, then all requests just use the object from cache. How can I do caching?

The easyiest way is to use static field of mywebmethod. IIS creates several ServiceHosts to serve requests. And in every servicehost static fields will be different.

I aso tried using `System.Web.HttpRuntime.Cache`. Again, I have some independent caches.

To clarify, I need to cache not the result of the request, but some intermediate data needed to process request.

So what can be a solution?

Comment: I've found that the real problem with IIS isnot in different servicehosts. They can succesfully share System.Web.Caching.Cache object available through HttpContext.Cache property (suitable for at least httpBindings). .Net creates one Cache object per AppDomain.  If IIS uses several worker processes in AppPool (in IIS 7, 10 by default), it obviously creates 100 AppDomains - and 10 separate Caches, naturally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running diferent services in separate AppDomains gives you crash-protection and some other, security-related benefits. If you are sure you need shared statics, consider using self-hosted servies.

I can think of only one way to achieve this using IIS: implement a [ServiceHostFactory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.activation.servicehostfactory.aspx), that will return custom ServiceHost that will start and stop multiple ServiceHosts under the hood. But it's waaay too hacky to be a piece of production code )

**Update** I stumbled upon this today, and this answer looks like a total mess. Different Service host do share one AppDomain if they reside inside the same IIS site, so static fields should be the same for all services.

Comment: Nope, it's just a tricky way of putting them into same appdomain, Not even sure you'll be able to create a fake service host to incapsulate them.
Again, I'd go with a self-hosted option.

Comment: One thing that stops me from running a self-hosted in potential loss of performance comparing to several servicehosta in IIS due to only one servicehost.

Comment: Multiple ServiceHost objects can co-exist in single process either it's w3wp.exe or any other process. I can't think of any reason for self-hosted service to be less performant.

Comment: Well, OK, thank you.

I'd wait some more before closing question to see if somebody will give another solution.